# How to I initialize a variable I created in Java?

Tags: java, class, object

```
class temperature {
    public double degrees = 0;
    public boolean isCelcius = false;

    public double returnDegrees(){
        return this.degrees;
    }

    public void setTemperature(double temeperatureT, boolean isCelciusT){
        this.degrees = temeperatureT;
        this.isCelcius = isCelciusT;
    }

    public void convertToC (){
        if (this.isCelcius == false) {
            this.degrees = ( 5 * (degrees - 32) ) / 9;
            this.isCelcius = true;
        }
        return;
    }

    public void convertToF (){
        if (this.isCelcius == true){
            this.degrees = ( ( 9 * degrees ) / 5 ) + 32;
            this.isCelcius = false;
        }
        return;
    }   
}



 public static temperature convertStringToTemperature(String tempString){
        temperature tempTemp;
        String split[] = tempString.split(" ");
        tempTemp.degrees = Double.parseDouble( split[0] )
        if (split[1] == "F")
            tempTemp.isCelcius = false;
        else if(split[1] == "C")
            tempTemp.isCelcius = true;
        else{
            System.out.println("error determining units");
            tempTemp.isCelcius = true;
        }

        return tempTemp; 
    }
```

For the Code:

```
>tempTemp.setTemperature(Double.parseDouble( split[0] ), true);
```

it says that the variable tempTemp may not have been initialized although it doesn't say it below for the other uses of that variable. What is my issue here?

Thanks, this is my first time making a custom class in java.

Comment: `temperature tempTemp = new temperature();`

Comment: Obligatory sidenote - Java naming conventions use `PascalCase` for class names.

Comment: By the way, always use an uppercase 1st letter when naming a class. And you can as well assign a `null` when you are sure, that before using a field it gets initialized by some statement, but then the compiler is happy.

Comment: Somebody downvoted this answer @ChrisChevalier, but I don't know why. It is a well written question despite being from a newbie perspective. You may want to read [ask], for reference, but well done anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you only created a reference to an object without creating the object itself.

```
temperature tempTemp = new temperature();
```

now the reference is initialized to point to a real object.

Answer (score 1):

`temperature tempTemp;` just creates local variable but not point/refer to any object or does not get assigned any value. Before invoking a method on an object, you need to get handle(reference) for the object.

```
temperature tempTemp = new temperature();
```

creates a local variable tempTemp and this variable refers/points to a temperature object and on the next line when `tempString.split(" ");` is executed, the split method is invoked on the object created on previous line.

Note that you can even initialize tempTemp variable with null, however that would result in NullPointerException in the next line.

Answer (score 1):

At the line

```
temperature tempTemp;
```

you only create the variable, but you still need to initialize it. In order to initialize it, you need to allocate it to an object such as

```
temperature tempTemp = new temperature();
```

Answer (score 0):

At the line

```
temperature temptemp;
```

you are declaring a variable called `temptemp` of `temperature` class. However, you are not initializing it. You initialize it by associating it to an object, like this:

```
temperature temptemp = new temperature();
```

in the code above you instantiate `temperature` and assign the object resulting from the instantiation to `temptemp`, which is of `temperature` class. So this line declares your variable and initializes it as well. If you do not specify what your object is, your intention cannot be guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Because `tempTemp` is not initialized inside `convertStringToTemperature` method.

This is an inbuilt feature that `Java` language has - this guarantees that the variable or objects are initialized before they can be used.

In your case, `tempTemp` instance of `temperature` class is local to `convertStringToTemperature` method and is not initialized.

And, this is true for local variables also. Try defining a primitive type inside your method without initializing and do a simple mathematical operation on it. You will get the same `error` from the `Java` compiler.

Also, start `Java` Class/ Type name with uppercase letter and for anything else follow camel casing as already pointed out in  other answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your convertStringToTemperature method on same class then you can use this.setTemperature() but your method can not be static in that case. As you cannot use "this" in a static context.
2. If your convertStringToTemperature method in different class You need to initialize your temperature object or you can pass temperature object in parameter like bellow:

`public static temperature convertStringToTemperature(String tempString,temperature tempTemp){`

```
         //temperature tempTemp = new temperature();            
        String split[] = tempString.split(" ");
        tempTemp.degrees = Double.parseDouble( split[0] );
        if (split[1] == "F")
            tempTemp.isCelcius = false;
        else if(split[1] == "C")
            tempTemp.isCelcius = true;
        else{
            System.out.println("error determining units");
            tempTemp.isCelcius = true;
        }

        return tempTemp; 
    }
```